# Gnome desktop environment stopped working in kali linux(debian based)

Tags: debian, gdm, kali-linux

Gnome desktop environment stopped working after change in `libudev.so.0` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and showing error:

```
cannot open shared libraries
```

I am trying too hard to get rid of this problem but unable to solve. I have 64 bit kali debian based linux(~).Now I donot have any files realted to `libudev.so.*` in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. From this my gdm is also not working.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrade and update? Please [edit] your post and include the _exact_ commands you ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after long try by just making live cd of kali linux and copy `libudev.so.0.13.0, libudev.so.0`(link) and paste it in `/lib/x86_64-login-gnu/`.